# iPhone external speak with Bluetooth and AirPlay?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, airplay, speakers

Most of the external speakers I've seen have either AirPlay [[B&W Zeppelin](http://www.bowers-wilkins.com/)] or Bluetooth [[Bose Soundlink, Jawbone Big Jambox](https://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/17/technology/personaltech/soundlink-and-big-jambox-speakers-go-wherever-you-go.html?partner=rssnyt&emc=rss)] but not both.  Anyone know of an external speaker system that has both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung has announced some products that support both.

Have a look at the high-end Samsung Audio Dock DA-E750, and the (only) a bit cheaper DA-E670.

I have never listened to the Samsung speakers, but I do find them a bit expensive compared to the already 'premium' price of the B&W Zeppelin Air for example, which still has a better reputation regarding audio quality, although preliminary reviews speak well about the quality of the Samsung speakers.

Also AirPlay is technically the superior technology, as it has a much larger bandwidth than Bluetooth, and transmits the audio uncompressed to the speaker. Unless you have specific reasons for needing Bluetooth, perhaps traveling with your speakers or streaming from non-Apple devices, I'd prefer an AirPlay speaker.